# PHP CURL function to handle GET OR POST actions against JSONWireProtocol

Tags: php, json, curl, selenium, webdriver

I haven't had any luck with creating a curl function that has all of the options to support GET OR POST actions against the json wire protocol as seen here 
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Messages

I had something along the lines of

```
class Myclass
{
    public static function curl($http_type, $full_url, $data=null){

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "$full_url");
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_type);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
       if($data && $http_type == "POST"){
        $data= http_build_query($data);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
       }

      $response = curl_exec($c);
      curl_close($c);
     return $response;
    }
}
```

and to have this execute upon something like this

```
$data_send = json_encode(array("url"=>"http://wwww.google.com"));
Myclass::curl("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/{$session_id}/url", $data_send);
```

and for the above to execute and return whatever the webdriver instance return on the curl action.

Comment: my question is how to properly send json POSTs to web driver via the JsonWireProtocol

Comment: You should follow the standards / specs, probably that line `$data= http_build_query($data);` is just plain wrong.

Comment: can you be a bit more detailed, what is plain wrong about it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed, what exactly is to be needed to be send to the remote endpoint and in which format? And can you then please outline how you ensure that you meet that format? I'm new to JsonWireProtocol so I need some help to help you.

Comment: When you start webdriver its accessible at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/{$session_id}/url and you can send via POST json. so for the above /url i would send  json_encode(array("url"=>"http://www.google.com")) but im not sure why i get 'null pointer exeception' when i try with the above curl function.

Comment: If you need to send the json, have you tried to not `http_build_query` it? That's normally only needed for HTML forms, which seems unrelated to what you want to do.

Comment: no luck with removing http_build_query.... this works                                                                 if( $capabilities === null) $capabilities['browserName'] = 'firefox';  
$json = array("desiredCapabilities" => $capabilities);  
$output = Boost::curl('POST', $this->webdriver_url . '/session', $json);  but not when i put /session/$session_id/url as the url